# Voice Recognition API

Tags: javascript, html, voice-recognition

I am trying to use the new VoiceRecognitionAPI available in Javascript (supported by chrome). In the app I am trying to develop, I need some very certain words, and mainly numbers... Unfourtenatly, the VoiceRecognition doesn't work smoothly and doesn't get the right words all the times, mainly with numbers like 4 becoming "for" or 3 becoming "three" etc.
I know there was some talk of an option to supply the VoiceRecognition with a grammar which will improve recognition, but it's not supported yet and won't be anytime soon...

Are there any approaches to improve the voice recognition, especially in an app that has a very small numbers of words in it?

Comment: Try http://syl22-00.github.io/pocketsphinx.js/ instead, you can force it to recognize numbers only with very high accuracy and the script will be more portable, it will work not just in chrome

Comment: From my expirience it is even less accurate than the google API

Answer (score 1):

Recently I found this project:
[annyang](https://www.talater.com/annyang/). 
However - I never played with it. I hope it will help you.